# Arch on Pogoplug running MJPG-streamer - How to disable LED on Logitech cam?

Tags: drivers, camera, arch-arm

I put Arch Linux on a Pogoplug v2 POGO-E02. I got wifi working and installed MJPG-Streamer from the AUR via packer.

The video stream is working fine, but as this is a security camera, I would like to disable the camera LED. My camera is a Logitech HD Pro C910. MJPG-Streamer has a flag for the LED, but it appears not to work for Logitech cams.

```
#Start mjpg_streamer service, use -b flag for background
# -l flag to disable LED
mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -n -y -r 800x448 -f 3 -l off"\
 -o "output_http.so -w /www -p 8080" -b
#then close console, service will continue running
```

I'd like to find the most appropriate, elegant way to get the camera LED to go off while streaming. Please don't say to put black tape on it. I'm not here at Stack Exchange for that kind of answer.

Something to do with the UVC driver?

---

Update:
Another part of a day of working on it.
There's a package which sounds promising, "uvcdynctrl", but it's not turning out to be easy to find and install. I've tried and failed to find these names in the main Arch library (using pacman) or in the AUR (using packer).

```
libwebcam
uvcvideo
uvcdynctrl
webcam-tools
```

Tomorrow I'll attempt to download and install this one manually on the Pogoplug:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/libwebcam/

If that's successful, I can see if I can follow this guide to disable the LED: https://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Video_Camera.html

I'll update the thread with any progress.